# NotifyDataSetChanged not working on Android 2.1

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an Android app which will support the Ice cream sandwich API but work on older devices such as running android 2.1.

I'm doing this by doing a check of what the current API version is, and if its post ice cream sandwich call one activity and then if its anything below, call a different activity.

I am allowing the user to perform a search, when it gets the results it then clears ArrayList and then adds the items from the search back in, and then calls the arrayadapter.notifydatasetchanged. This code I've copied and pasted from the ICS version into the pre ICS version, the ICS works fine but on the pre ics version the list view doesn't get updated. Below is the code that I have.

```
public void performSearch(ArrayList<Spanned> searchPasswords)
    {
        if (searchPasswords.size() > 0)
        {
            btnClearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            passwords.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchPasswords.size(); i++)
            {
                passwords.add(searchPasswords.get(i));
            }

            passwordArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            btnClearSearch.setOnClickListener(mBtnClearSearch);
            common.showToastMessage(searchPasswords.size() + " result(s) found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            common.showToastMessage("No search results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

I've debugged this function so it is definetely calling it, and its displaying the toast messags with saying how many results were found, but the list view doesn't get changed.

### Update

I have just made a discovery which is a bit confusing. As a test in the function that does the initial loading of the list view I manually create a new search `ArrayList<Spanned>` and pass this to the same `PerformSearch(ArrayList<Spanned>`) that I am having the problem with and this works without any problems.

The problem with the performSearch not updating the ListView only seems to happen when it is being called from onActivityResult. I know that onActivityResult is working fine as when the performSearch function is called it then prints out there is 1 result(s) found so its definitely got data just the list view doesn't get refreshed from the onActivityResult calling the performSearch function.

Comment: What is your passwords object? I think you should clear your passwordAdapter, add the new items to the adapter and then notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @Joris the passwords object is an ArrayList<Spanned> type

Comment: I dont know much from only the code snippet you've pasted but from what I see there is no persistent link between passwords and the passwordsArrayAdapter....passwordsArrayAdapter initialises itself with the elements of passwords and passwordsArrayAdapter will not know when passwords changes.

To add new items you should call passwordsArrayAdapter.add(searchPasswords).Dont bother calling notifyDataSetChanged() explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions, I've managed to find out what the problem was.

In my OnResume method  for the activity I call a function called populateListArray which retrieves all of the information from the database and lists in the ListView.

When the activity was returned it was calling the OnResume method so after it got the results it then reset the list view back with all the original content.

To get round it I added a variable called `performingSearch` which I initialise to false. When I perform the search I set this to true and in the onResume, if the variable is true I don't do anything and after the perform search function has finished I set the variable back to false again.

Thanks everyone again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
passwordArrayAdapter = new WHAT_EVER_ADAPTER_THIS_IS(searchPasswords, extra_constructor_params);
YOUR_LIST_VIEW.setAdapter(passwordArrayAdapter)
```

instead of:

```
    passwordArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I did try that as well, knew I was forgetting to say something in the question, but this didn't make any difference either

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Neither notidfyDataSetChanged() nor setAdapter() worked.

Finally I figured out a solution which may not be as efficient as using notifyDataSetChanged() but it works.

```
/**
 * Updates courses' list adapter.
 */
private void updateListAdapter()
{
    final ArrayAdapter a = (ArrayAdapter) coursesList.getAdapter();

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            populteCoursesList();
            a.clear();

            for (MainScreenListModel model : listModels)
            {
                a.add(model);
            }
            a.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

courseList is my custom list. populateCoursesList() gets the data from db and listModels is a Vector of models for list view.
As you can see I have to clear the adapter and fill it once again.

Comment: thanks I've tried this, but no difference unfortunately, still doesn't update anything

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is to forget to clear the adapter, if you try it like this it should work:

```
public void performSearch(ArrayList<Spanned> searchPasswords)
    {
        if (searchPasswords.size() > 0)
        {
            btnClearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            passwordArrayAdapter.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < searchPasswords.size(); i++)
            {
                passwordArrayAdapter.add(searchPasswords.get(i));
            }
            passwordArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            btnClearSearch.setOnClickListener(mBtnClearSearch);
            common.showToastMessage(searchPasswords.size() + " result(s) found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        else
        {
            common.showToastMessage("No search results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I've tried this but its throwing an exception saying ``java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`` on the ``passwordArrayAdapter.addAll()`` function even though eclipse doesn't have any errors.

Comment: Oops, I forgot you're targeting Android 2.1, addAll() is a Android >- 3.0 function. Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
passwords.clear();
for (int i = 0; i < searchPasswords.size(); i++)
{
  passwords.add(searchPasswords.get(i));
}
passwordArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As per the code, u r modifying the list(passwords), but is it the same instance that is being used by the adapter (passwordArrayAdapter). If not then notifyDataSetChanged() wont work.

From my understanding, you  can either set the list again with a new instance of passwordArrayAdapter.

```
ur_list_view.setAdapter(new PasswordArrayAdapter(newly_formed_password_list, and other parameters));
```

or use getter and setter to update the list(passwords) and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Boardy Did u try my solution??

Comment: sorry for the delay in getting back to you, haven't had the time to look at it recently. I have tried it but unfortunately still no luck with it

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much from only the code snippet you've pasted but from what I see there is no persistent link between passwords and the passwordsArrayAdapter....passwordsArrayAdapter initialises itself with the elements of passwords and passwordsArrayAdapter will not know when passwords changes. To add new items you should call passwordsArrayAdapter.add(searchPasswords).Dont bother calling notifyDataSetChanged() explicitly.

```
public void performSearch(ArrayList<Spanned> searchPasswords)
    {
       if (searchPasswords.size() > 0)
       {
            btnClearSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           passwordArrayAdapter.clear();
           passwordArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
         for (int i = 0; i < searchPasswords.size(); i++)
         {
               passwordArrayAdapter.add(searchPasswords.get(i));
         }
            btnClearSearch.setOnClickListener(mBtnClearSearch);
            common.showToastMessage(searchPasswords.size() + " result(s) found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       }
        else
        {
            common.showToastMessage("No search results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
```

I wouldnt think there'd be a relation with the onActivityResult bit -- the above code should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyOnChange(false)` before clearing and adding the new entries. Otherwise, the `clear()` and every `add()` internally trigger a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which, as I experienced, confuses the ListView. Keep your explicit `notifyDataSetChanged()`, which also resets the internal `notifyOnChange` flag to `true` again.